# WP7 binding UserControl using MVVM

Tags: windows-phone-7, mvvm, user-controls

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Binding between Usercontrol with listbox and parent control (MVVM)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2949956/binding-between-usercontrol-with-listbox-and-parent-control-mvvm)

I’m trying to bind a UserControl to property on my main page’s viewmodel
The code looks like this:

UserControl xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="myUserControl"  ....>
     <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="{StaticResource PhoneChromeBrush}" >
         <ListBox Name="myListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=myItemsSource}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

the codebehind looks like this:

```
public partial class myUserControl : UserControl
{
     public static DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
                   DependencyProperty.Register("myItemsSource", 
                   typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(myUserControl), null);

     public IEnumerable myItemsSource
     {
        get
        {
            return (IEnumerable)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value);
        }
    }
}
```

The UC is used like this in the main page:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage DataContext="{Binding myViewModel, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"  ....>
   <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel">
        <uc:myUserControl x:Name="ucList" myItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataList}"/>
   </Grid>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

and the viewModel for the main page look like this:

```
public class myViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<myObject> DataList
    {
        get
        {
            return _datalist;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_dataList != value)
            {
               _dataList = value;
               RaisePropertyChanged("DataList");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But when the DataList property is set, the uc List in not populated.
What i'm I missing ?

Answer (score 0):

It's still early and I haven't had my coffee yet, but it looks to me like you might need a data template for your list items. You've defined the `ItemsSource` but not told the control how to render the items themselves.

What does your list contain? Try binding a data template to one of the list item properites, like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="myUsercontrol"  ....>     
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="{StaticResource PhoneChromeBrush}" >         
    <ListBox Name="myListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=myItemsSource}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding SomeListItemProperty}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

EDIT: Are you by chance using MVVM Light? I saw that you mentioned `{StaticResource = Locator}` in one of the comments. That would be helpful to know.

One other thing you might try is checking if your `UserControl` is in its own namespace. If you put it in a `UserControl` folder, it might be. I've had some issues with binding a `UserControl` when it wasn't in the same namespace as the `ViewModel`.

Comment: Adding this to the main page
 <ListBox Name="myListBox2" ItemsSource="{BindingPath=DataList}"/>
works fine without setting the data template, and it didn't help on the UC.

Comment: Yes, I'm using MVVM Light, and yes the UC is in another NS. I will try move it over.

Comment: If you are still trying to figure this out, post a link to a sample project that duplicates the issue. T started to build my own, but there are too many pieces I don't know about how you're structuring the app.