# Issues in WP7 binding to properties in custom User Control

Tags: windows-phone-7, user-controls

So I'm trying to make a custom user control for a Windows Phone 7 application that I call a ColoredTextBlock. You can probably guess what it does.

Anyway, ColoredTextBlock contains a TextBlock which I want the user to be able to set the Text and Style for.

If I try just making a simple property that just passes through, such as:

```
    public string Text
    {
        get { return Label.Text; }
        set
        {
            Label.Text = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Text");
        }
    }
```

It causes a very cryptic ArgumentException. However if I set the input text, like:

```
 <MyRepresentative:ColoredTextBlock Text="Some Text" BackgroundColor="Red" />
```

Everything works out exactly as I'd expect.

If on the other hand, I go with the more advanced route of using a Dependency property and binding the Inner TextBlock to this property, and then binding the external data to this property as well, nothing shows up.

```
    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(TextProperty, value);
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Label");
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(ColoredTextBlock), null);
```

Again though, if I insert the text manually, the whole thing just works.

Here's the xaml of my custom control:

```
 <UserControl
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
x:Class="MyRepresentative.ColoredTextBlock"
d:DesignWidth="456" d:DesignHeight="43"
    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <Rectangle Stroke="Black">
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="{Binding DimBackgroundColor}" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="{Binding BrightBackgroundColor}" Offset="0.85"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="{Binding BrightBackgroundColor}" Offset="0.15"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="{Binding DimBackgroundColor}" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" Margin="5,0" d:LayoutOverrides="Width"/>
    </Grid>
 </UserControl>
```

I've been racking my brain on this for the better part of the day, and looking at so many different articles, and I'm certain at this point that I'm missing something small, but I just can't find it.

**UPDATE 1**: After looking into it further, it appears that for some reason even though I set it up with bindings, it doesn't appear that this is actually being set, at least as far as I can tell.

**UPDATE 2**: Based on the comment, you asked about making sure that my DataContext was set correctly. Ya, this was one of the first things I thought of. I have a lines below in my xaml.

```
 <MyRepresentative:ColoredTextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" BackgroundColor="Red" />
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextLargeStyle}" />
```

So the first element doesn't show up (at all), unless I change to something like `Text="Some text"`. The second element works perfectly without error.

Comment: You did not include the code where you set the DataContext (for your {Binding} to work). Also, are you notifying on the wrong property name? (You call NotifyPropertyChanged("Label") on a property called "Text")

Comment: Hey Shahar, I tried to address your comment in the updates above. The issue with the names was because I was trying a number of different things to try to make it work. I did however make sure that they were consistent now.

Comment: I meant your datacontext inside your control. You ref yourself at the top - but in your sample code that works, you are binding to "Title" and in the control you are binding to "Text"

Comment: So the ViewModel element that has the actual text is Title. I'm binding that to the Text property on my UserControl, and I'm binding the Text property of the TextBlock to the Text property of my UserControl as well. Hope that fixes some of the confusion.

Comment: Gotcha - so this may just be my lack of understanding here... Is the RelativeSource Self you have there essentially point to the **DataSource** of the control (as opposed to **this** [the control instance] which will have your property)? From reading about RelativeSource, that's what I am gathering. Did you try changing the binding in the control to be to {Title} just to see if it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up figuring out the answer to this problem myself, although it took me a while, and a bit of searching.  The answer was actually inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2950197/1017797).

**Answer:**

Instead of binding to the root element using:

```
 DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

Such as I did in the example above:

```
 <UserControl
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
     xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
     mc:Ignorable="d"
     x:Class="MyRepresentative.ColoredTextBlock"
     d:DesignWidth="456" d:DesignHeight="43"
     DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
```

Bind instead to the LayoutRoot, in this case, my Grid Element.

```
 <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
```

This can be done in your code behind, in the constructor, like I did here:

```
    public ColoredTextBlock()
    {
        ...
        LayoutRoot.DataContext = this;
        ...
    }
```

**Explanation:**

I don't fully understand why this works to be honest, and if someone can explain it, please edit.

It seems to have to do with overriding existing bindings when you bind to the root element. As such, when you try to bind an external element to an element of this control, it will fail, because that binding isn't accessible.

Hope that helps others who come across the same problem as me!

Answer (score 2):

I had some real trouble doing the same thing as yourself with no luck, the only entries I found talked about this approach not working (sorry I can't find them any more).

I did have success if I set the bindings up via C#. I have an example of this [shared here](https://bitbucket.org/nigel.sampson/compiled-experience-toolkit/src/1b7333af3dd8/Demo/Controls/ItemValue.xaml.cs).

**Edit**: Another solution I've just found is to use [Element Name bindings](http://alan.beech.me.uk/2011/04/25/adding-a-dependency-property-to-a-wp7-usercontrol/).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.  I checked them both out. Unfortunately, they don't seem to give me any better results then what I'm getting right now :(